# unable to remove the validation classes while clicking the cancel option in dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i'm using [these validation](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) for my application. these works fine, when i'm using these in dialog box it works but after showing validations and pressing cancel the validations remains appear in the back-end page. Suggest some alternative like removeClass() on clicking the cancel option in my dialog box.

Comment: It doesn't work when you use validations in *what* dialog box?? Clarify your question and add examples if you will.

Comment: @ WTK - on a jquery model form dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On cancel you should execute

```
$('form').validationEngine('hideAll')
```

And all validation errors will be hidden